# C# PKCS signatures - generate .p7s file from the attached signature byte[]

Tags: c#, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I'm developing a system that needs to sign files. I already have a function that receives the `byte[]` of data to sign and the X509 Certificate and computes the signature using `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs` namespace. It's important to note that we need the signature to be attached, so for verification we use the file, the attached signature and the certificate.

The thing is that this function returns a `byte[]` as signature. Right now for serializing it, I am using `Base64` encoding, but I saw that the standard is to use `.p7s` files.

So, how do I generate a `.p7s` file from the `byte[]` of the attached signature?

Also, is there a way to add a timestamp to the signature and then to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

p7s is a detached PKCS#7 signature itself. It can be (optionally) base64-encoded and that's all, there's no other formatting that needs to be applied.

Yes, you can timestamp PKCS#7 signature. You need to read RFC 3161 and implement it yourself. You can use [PKI components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) of our SecureBlackbox product. Our components let you sign and timestamp data using PKCS#7 and CMS (extension and descendant of PKCS#7). I am not aware of free timestamping clients for PKCS#7, though some might exist.

Answer (score 0):

Now it possible using X509Certificate2 class

```
public static byte[] Sign(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    if(data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    if(certificate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");

    // setup the data to sign
    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, certificate);

    // create the signature
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
    return signedCms.Encode();
}
```